# Extra, changing character in output file MATLAB fprintf

Tags: matlab, output, printf

I have two data structures:

```
atomName <855*1 cell>
atomSASA <855*1 double>
```

which I am using in code to produce an output file:

```
%write out SASA values for individual atoms to file
results_file = fopen('output.txt','w');
fprintf(results_file,'SASA for Individual Atoms: \n');
i=1;
while i < (855)
    fprintf(results_file,'Atom %s %s: %.3f\n',i,cell2mat(atomName(i)),atomSASA(i));
    i = i + 1;
end
```

The file seems correct for the first 32 lines, but starting at line 33, there is an extra character after the word Atom. The character changes each line, eventually going through digits, capital letters A-Z, lower letters a-z etc. I would like to remove this extra character from each line:

```
Atom ! HG23: 6.286
Atom " N: 0.000
Atom # CA: 0.000
Atom $ C: 0.000
Atom % O: 0.000
Atom & CB: 0.000
Atom ' CG: 0.000
Atom ( CD1: 0.000
Atom ) CD2: 0.000
Atom * CE1: 0.000
Atom + CE2: 0.000
Atom , CZ: 0.000
Atom - OH: 0.000
Atom . H: 0.000
Atom / HA: 0.000
Atom 0 HB2: 0.000
Atom 1 HB3: 0.000
Atom 2 HD1: 0.000
Atom 3 HD2: 0.000
Atom 4 HE1: 0.000
Atom 5 HE2: 0.000
Atom 6 HH: 0.000
Atom 7 N: 0.000
Atom 8 CA: 0.000
Atom 9 C: 0.000
Atom : O: 0.000
Atom ; CB: 0.000
Atom < CG: 0.000
Atom = CD: 0.000
Atom > CE: 1.208
Atom ? NZ: 1.312
Atom @ H: 0.000
Atom A HA: 0.000
Atom B HB2: 0.000
Atom C HB3: 0.000
Atom D HG2: 0.000
Atom E HG3: 0.000
Atom F HD2: 0.000
Atom G HD3: 0.000
Atom H HE2: 0.000
Atom I HE3: 33.979
Atom J HZ1: 0.000
Atom K HZ2: 0.000
Atom L HZ3: 44.513
Atom M N: 0.000
Atom N CA: 0.000
Atom O C: 0.000
Atom P O: 0.000
Atom Q CB: 0.000
Atom R CG: 0.000
Atom S CD1: 0.000
Atom T CD2: 0.000
Atom U H: 0.000
Atom V HA: 0.000
Atom W HB2: 0.000
Atom X HB3: 0.000
Atom Y HG: 0.000
Atom Z HD11: 0.000
Atom [ HD12: 0.000
Atom \ HD13: 0.000
Atom ] HD21: 0.000
Atom ^ HD22: 0.000
Atom _ HD23: 0.000
Atom ` N: 0.000
Atom a CA: 0.000
Atom b C: 0.000
Atom c O: 0.000
Atom d CB: 0.000
Atom e CG1: 0.000
Atom f CG2: 0.000
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should probably replace your `fprintf` by:

```
fprintf(results_file,'Atom %i %s: %.3f\n', i, atomName{i}, atomSASA(i));
```

To print an integer, you should use `%i` or `%d`, with `%s` an integer gets interpreted as an ascii value:

```
>> fprintf('as ascii: %s\n', 66)
as ascii: B
>> fprintf('as number: %i\n', 66)
as number: 66
```

One other thing: it is easier to write `atomName{i}` instead of `cell2mat(atomName(i))`. Indexing a cell array with curly braces gives you the content of the i-th cell, what you want. Indexing it with normal parenthesis will give you a 1x1 cell array with the content of the i-th cell:

```
>> atoms = {'aa','bb','cc'}
atoms = 
    'aa'    'bb'    'cc'
>> class(atoms{2})
ans =
char
>> class(atoms(2))
ans =
cell
```

See [the manual](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/access-data-in-a-cell-array.html).